# external link not workin in fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Is there any setting for a link embedded into fancybox ?
My link is not working

## html

```
<button href="#show_popup_link" class="show_popup">Click to open Fancybox</button>
<div id="show_popup_link" class="show_popup" style="display: none;">
    Hello, I need this link to work this 
    <a href="http://www.google.com">External Link</a>
</div>
```

## jQuery

```
$(document).ready({
    $(".show_popup").fancybox();)
};
```

Fancybox opens but the link doesnot seem to be working.

Jsfiddle link:
http://jsfiddle.net/n2dHC/7/

Comment: You would have to put descriptions in the title attribute, and if you are linking in any HTML use HTML entities.  And possibly, perhaps this code `style="display: none;"` is making it not visible?

Comment: My use-case here is to link to external links as shown in the example above and as in jsfiddle. And I didn't get you @SolomonClosson

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get rid of the `class="show_popup"` code on the following HTML:

```
<div id="show_popup_link" class="show_popup" style="display: none;">
```

So, should be this instead:

```
<div id="show_popup_link" style="display: none;">
```

Because you have the same class name defined on the `button` element, this causes fancybox trying to open it up again, but can't because it is already open.

[Working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n2dHC/10/)

Comment: Correct, the OP is making the class `show_popup` the trigger and the target at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

In the given example you had given same class name "show_popup" for both link and division. so even when you click the "External Link" the division.fancybox(); is calling. Please change the division class name and try.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/n2dHC/9/). Please check the fiddle link.

```
<div id="show_popup_link" class="show_popup11" style="display: none;">
    Hello, I need this link to work 
    <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">External Link</a>
</div>
```